# Integrating Facebook Login into Swift Framework

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, facebook-sdk-4.0

I have an IOS project in **Swift Framework target**. I follow the tutorials to integrate Facebook SDK (for Login) into my framework. I compile my framework with no error.

Then I create a **Swift Application** that integrate my framework. I compile it with an error as below:

```
Ld /Users/youngworld/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App3-bsiqheuhcocalbbvjkulchclprhg/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/App3.app/App3 normal x86_64
    cd /Users/youngworld/IOSProjects/App3
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.0
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.1.sdk -L/Users/youngworld/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App3-bsiqheuhcocalbbvjkulchclprhg/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/youngworld/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App3-bsiqheuhcocalbbvjkulchclprhg/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/youngworld/IOSProjects/App3 -F/Users/youngworld/IOSProjects/App3/App3 -filelist /Users/youngworld/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App3-bsiqheuhcocalbbvjkulchclprhg/Build/Intermediates/App3.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/App3.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/App3.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -mios-simulator-version-min=8.0 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -L/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/youngworld/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App3-bsiqheuhcocalbbvjkulchclprhg/Build/Intermediates/App3.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/App3.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/App3.swiftmodule -framework YWSDK -framework YWSDK -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/youngworld/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App3-bsiqheuhcocalbbvjkulchclprhg/Build/Intermediates/App3.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/App3.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/App3_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/youngworld/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App3-bsiqheuhcocalbbvjkulchclprhg/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/App3.app/App3

ld: framework not found FBSDKLoginKit for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Someone show me the way to fix it.

Thank you!

Comment: do you use parse on your project?

Comment: search in the project parse.framework

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your Project contains Bolts.framework, FBSDKCoreKit.framework and FBSDKLoginKit.framework for facebook login integration in your application.
Given link will help you:
https://developers.facebook.com/apps/174570549964701/fb-login/quickstart/

(Note: If you manually added frameworks to your project then recheck that frameworks are in your project's folder not anywhere else like in Downloads folder. And if you added frameworks by installing pods then that are in your project's "Frameworks" folder.)